# Реализовать итерационную функцию на python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
def main(b, n, a, z):
    result = 0
    term = 0
    chislo = (z ** 2 - 56 * z) ** 2 / 76
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        product = 1
        for c in range(1, b + 1):
            summation = 0
            summation += c - k ** 3 - c ** 7
            product *= summation
            result += product
    for j in range(1, a + 1):
        term = term + (20 * j ** 3 - chislo)
    result -= term
    return result
```

Не понимаю в чем ошибка, с таким решением проходит первые два теста, еще пробовал 13 строчку, перенести в цикл j , не проходило вообще тест , не хватало 0.03.

Comment: Какую тему перед этим проходили? Не было там слов про точность вычислений? Поднимайте конспекты.

Comment: Тут ошибка в коде скорее всего, а не в точности вычислений...

Comment: А зачем вы вторую сумму считаете **внутри** первой суммы и произведения? Там же нет скобок, она явно отдельно должна считаться, она и по переменным явно не зависима от первой суммы и произведения. Вернее, вы её даже не считаете, а просто берёте значение по последнему `j` в цикле. Но в любом случае - вынесите подсчёт второй суммы **на верхний уровень**, отдельно от первой суммы-произведения. Т.е. `f = П(С1(...)) - С2(...)`, вот так это на верхнем уровне должно выглядеть, а сейчас вы пытаетесь сделать что-то типа `f = П(С1(С2(...)))`

Comment: Сделал , но все равно не хватает 0.03 для верного теста

Comment: Добавьте исправленный код в вопрос, вы можете его редактировать. Я посмотрю, что не так.

Comment: Я уже сам из интереса код ваш переделал, всё правильно считается, формулы у вас правильно запрограммированы, а вот циклы нет. Просто разберитесь, где у вас сумма, где произведение, где вычитание, и всё. Предоставите изменённый код - подскажу, что не так. За вас код полностью не буду переписывать - это не по правилам для учебных заданий.

Comment: Переделал , в самом вопросе вроде как

Comment: Ну вот как вы думаете - посчитается у вас так сумма: `for ... ; term = ...`? Где тут сумма? Сумма - это когда что-то прибавляется, а не просто присваивается. И второе, `result -= term` нужно делать **не в цикле**, а после его окончания.

Comment: Я не внимательно исправил, вот сейчас посмотрите, переделанный сейчас все равно ошибка
Подробные сведения об ошибке:
Получено:
2.82e+05

Входные данные:
2, 7, 3, 0.15

Comment: `result += product` нужно на одну табуляцию влево - ведь это должно делаться после окончания цикла. И вроде всё остальное уже правильно, только много лишнего, но это ладно.

Comment: Все спасибо решилось!

Comment: Осталось избавиться от лишней суеты с `summation`, ну да ладно, главное работает. А то пара строк в общем-то лишние

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведённая формула явно имеет такой формат:

```
f = Сумма(Произведение(...)) - Сумма(...)
```

То есть суммы должны считаться независимо друг от друга, а потом вычитаться. У вас же получается что-то типа:

```
f = Сумма(Произведение(Сумма(...)))
```

Из-за этого подсчёт неправильный. Сами формулы сделаны правильно. То есть код должен выглядеть не так:

```
for ...
    for ...
        for ...
```

А так:

```
for ...
    for ...
for ...
```

Это в общих чертах.

Comment: Вроде исправил, выше можете посмотреть